# How to combine these mysql queries

Tags: php, mysql

Query 1

```
$query = "SELECT stock_issue.*,stock_item.item_name 
  FROM stock_issue,stock_item
  WHERE stock_issue.idate>=$from 
    AND stock_issue.idate<=$to 
    AND stock_issue.item_id=stock_item.ID 
ORDER BY stock_issue.idate DESC";
```

Query 2

```
$query = "SELECT stock_purchase.*,stock_item.item_name
  FROM stock_purchase,stock_item 
  WHERE stock_purchase.pdate>=$from 
    AND stock_purchase.pdate<=$to
    AND stock_purchase.itemid=stock_item.ID 
  ORDER BY stock_purchase.pdate DESC";
```

Please Help me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try With this code

```
SELECT stock_issue.*,stock_item.item_name 
  FROM stock_issue,stock_item
  WHERE stock_issue.idate>='$from' 
    AND stock_issue.idate<='$to' 
    AND stock_issue.item_id=stock_item.ID 
ORDER BY stock_issue.idate DESC

UNION

SELECT stock_purchase.*,stock_item.item_name
  FROM stock_purchase,stock_item 
  WHERE stock_purchase.pdate>='$from' 
    AND stock_purchase.pdate<='$to'
    AND stock_purchase.itemid=stock_item.ID 
  ORDER BY stock_purchase.pdate DESC
```

That is like

```
$sql=$query1.'UNION'.$query2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the union to combine it.

```
(SELECT stock_issue.*,stock_item.item_name FROM stock_issue,stock_item where stock_issue.idate>=$from and stock_issue.idate<=$to and stock_issue.item_id=stock_item.ID) UNION (SELECT stock_purchase.*,stock_item.item_name FROM stock_purchase,stock_item where stock_purchase.pdate>=$from and stock_purchase.pdate<=$to and stock_purchase.itemid=stock_item.ID)
```

Comment: thaks for your reply...i got it

Answer (score 0):

Try this with UNION

```
  $sql="SELECT stock_issue.*,stock_item.item_name FROM stock_issue,stock_item where stock_issue.idate>=$from and stock_issue.idate<=$to and stock_issue.item_id=stock_item.ID ORDER BY stock_issue.idate DESC
         UNION
        SELECT stock_purchase.*,stock_item.item_name FROM stock_purchase,stock_item where stock_purchase.pdate>=$from and stock_purchase.pdate<=$to and stock_purchase.itemid=stock_item.ID ORDER BY stock_purchase.pdate DESC";
```

Comment: thaks for your reply...i got it